# ¿Como permitir solo números o letras en un Entry en Python?

Tags: python, validación, interfaz-gráfica

Hola estoy practicando un poco realizando interfaces gráficas con Python me ha surgido un problema, como puedo permitir que en un Entry solo se puedan ingresar números o letras según sea el caso.

[image: Ventana]

Esta es la ventana con la que estoy trabajando, por ejemplo, tengo pensado que el campo Código acceso y teléfono solo admita números, mientras que el campo nombre solo admita letras al igual que correo aunque aquí también puede ir un @ o .
Si alguien sabe alguna forma se lo agradecería mucho
Les dejo mi código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox


  
class VentanaEjemplo:

    def __init__(self,ventana):

        self.ventana = ventana
        ventana.title("Datos")
        ventana.config(background="light blue")
        
        self.frame=Frame(ventana,width=500,height=400,background="light blue")
        self.frame.pack()

        self.codigo=Label(self.frame, text="Código acceso:",background="light green",font=("Comic Sans Ms",12),width=10,anchor='e')
        self.codigo.place(x=10,y=40)

        self.nombre=Label(self.frame, text="Nombre:",background="light green",font=("Comic Sans Ms",12),width=10,anchor='e')
        self.nombre.place(x=10,y=100)

        self.telefono=Label(self.frame, text="Telefono:",background="light green",font=("Comic Sans Ms",12),width=10,anchor='e')
        self.telefono.place(x=10,y=160)

        self.correo=Label(self.frame, text="Correo:",background="light green",font=("Comic Sans Ms",12),width=10,anchor='e')
        self.correo.place(x=10,y=210)



        self.codigoT=Entry(self.frame,background="white",font=("Comic Sans Ms",12),width=15,justify="center")
        self.codigoT.place(x=120,y=40)

        self.nombreT=Entry(self.frame,background="white",font=("Comic Sans Ms",12),width=15,justify="center")
        self.nombreT.place(x=120,y=100)

        self.telefonoT=Entry(self.frame,background="white",font=("Comic Sans Ms",12),width=15,justify="center")
        self.telefonoT.place(x=120,y=160)

        self.correoT=Entry(self.frame,background="white",font=("Comic Sans Ms",12),width=15,justify="center")
        self.correoT.place(x=120,y=210)

        self.enviar=Button(self.frame,text="Enviar",cursor="hand2",comman=self.verificar)
        self.enviar.place(x=30,y=290)

        self.abrirImagen=Button(self.frame,text="Abrir Imagen",cursor="hand2")
        self.abrirImagen.place(x=150,y=290)

        self.abrirVentana=Button(self.frame,text="Abrir ventana",cursor="hand2")
        self.abrirVentana.place(x=280,y=290)



    def verificar(self):

        pass

        #MessageBox.showinfo("saludo","Hola mundo")




root = Tk()
miVentana = VentanaEjemplo(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por ejemplo, para el campo *código acceso* puedes manejar el evento `"<KeyRelease>"`:

```py
self.codigoT.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: self.verificar())
```

Dentro del método `self.verificar` puedes obtener el código introducido:

```py
def verificar(self):
    codigo = self.codigoT.get()
```

Una vez obtenido el código introducido puedes iterar sobre cada uno de sus *caracteres* y comprobar si se trata de un número:

```py
def verificar(self):
    codigo = self.codigoT.get()

    for i in codigo:
        if i not in '0123456789':
            pass
```

Finalmente, si `i` no está en `"0123456789"` es que no es un número y debes eliminarlo. Para ello puedes utilizar el método `tkinter.Entry.delete`:

```py
def verificar(self):
    codigo = self.codigoT.get()

    for i in codigo:
        if i not in '0123456789':
            self.codigoT.delete(codigo.index(i), codigo.index(i)+1)
```

Observa que puedes comprobar si un caracter pertenece a cualquier secuencia. Puedes sustituir `"0123456789"` por cualquier otro *filtro*. Sin embargo, los objetos de la clase `str` en *python* tienen métodos que te interesa revisar. Siendo `i` un `str`:

- `i.isdigit()`: Devuelve `True` si `i` solamente contiene caracteres numéricos.
- `i.isalpha()`: Devuelve `True` si `i` solamente contiene caracteres del alfabeto.
- `i.isalnum()`: Devuelve `True` si `i` solamente contiene caracteres alfanuméricos (letras y números, pero no caracteres especiales).

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Usando expresiones regulares puedes lograr eso.

```
def verificar(self):
    errors = []
    if not re.search(r'^[0-9]+$', codigoT.get()):
        error.append('invalid code)
   if not re.search(r'^[0-9]+$', telefonoT.get()):
        error.append('invalid phone)
   if not re.search(r'^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+([.]\w{2,3})+$', correoT.get()):
        error.append('invalid email)
   return errors
```

si erros está vazio quiere decir que todos fueron verificados correctamente

más sobre [regex en pythobn](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

más sobre [regex](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)